# How can i show the full attribute path Joi validation

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

Im using Joi validation, I have too many attributes which look same with others in the body, i cant  show the full path, it just show that something is missing, without letting the user know what is wrong, take a look at the following

```
body: {
            member: Joi.object().required().keys({
                id: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string(),
                email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
            }),
            member2: Joi.object().required().keys({
                id: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string(),
                email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
            })
}
```

as you see above those two members have same attributes as they should be 
if an id missing it just show id is required regardless where is missing 
im trying to do something like the following if member2 is missing but i got failed

```
{message:  member2.id is required}
```

not just show id is missing.
any soltuions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As work around You can use `.lable()` in JOI .lable will solve this issue

`.label()` can wrap the attribute name at runtime in validation. 
for example

```
body: {
            member: Joi.object().required().keys({
                id: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string(),
                email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
            }),
            member2: Joi.object().required().keys({
                id: Joi.string().required(),
                phone: Joi.string(),
                email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
            })
}
```

Now let us suppose that the phone member.phone has error and member2.phone doesn't

the validation output will be `phone` is not match. this confusing a bit! which phone ? is it member2 or member one ? now let us try to use `.lable()`

```
body: {
                member: Joi.object().required().keys({
                    id: Joi.string().required(),
                    phone: Joi.string().label('member.phone'),
                    email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
                }),
                member2: Joi.object().required().keys({
                    id: Joi.string().required(),
                    phone: Joi.string().label('member2.phone'),
                    email: Joi.string().required().regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/)
                })
    }
```

the validation output now will be

```
error member.phone doesn't match
```